# symfony2 : kernel.debug is always false

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I use assetic to bundle css and js files together and I've noticed that even in debug mode they are bundled. That should only happen when kernel.debug is false.

So I've tried the following:

original :

```
 assetic:
   debug:         %kernel.debug%
```

force to false:

```
 assetic:
   debug:         false
```

force to true :

```
 assetic:
  debug:         true
```

When I force to false, files are bundled. When I force true, files are not bundled. When I leave %kernel.debug%, files are bundled.

Why is %kernel.debug% equals to false even though in app_dev I've set it to true:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

 require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

 $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

**EDIT**

```
assetic:
debug:         %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    uglifyjs2:  
        bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
        apply_to: "\.js$"      
    uglifycss:
        bin: /usr/bin/uglifycss
        apply_to: "\.css$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess youre trying to to dump assets using the `assetic:dump` command.

In order to avoid the creation of debug files add `--no-debug` to the command.

you could further execute the command explicitly within the production environment adding `--env=prod`. So finally ...

```
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

... will not create the debug files.

Please note that `--no-debug` does not work in combination with `--watch`.

Comment: That's what I do when I move on to production. But why would I need to do that when developing ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by files get "bundled" ? are you dumping your assets and using twig's `asset` function or assetic-bundle's `stylesheets` or `javascripts` functions? do you declare your assets in configuration ( assetic -> assets ) or inside the twig templates? please clarify your workflow a bit :)

Comment: I'm not dumping anything (I do it in production but not in the dev environment).  I use the asset function in templates and I configure assetic in config.yml. I've edited my original post with my assetic settings. As you can see I use uglifyjs and uglifycss. But again, that should be active while in debug.